# Parsing nested object using reduce() and Typescript

Tags: typescript, reduce, nested-object

I'm actually trying to convert some Javascript code to Typescript, but I'm having issues on following function. Its purpose is to parse some content (nested object built from a JSON.parse()), when called like, for ex.: `t('common.error')`.

```js
const i18nContent = {
  common: {
    error: {
    missing_translation: 'Missing translation',
    missing_posts: 'Some articles are not available in this language',
  },
  languages_available: 'This article is available in other languages'
}

const t = (key) => {
  const kArray = key.split('.')

  // Parsing possibly nested object
  const keyValue = kArray.reduce((o, k) => ((o && o[k] !== 'undefined') ? o[k] : undefined), i18nContent)

  return keyValue || key
}
```

I tried this approach, which seems to work but seems quite ugly to me... :/

```js
type I18nContent = Record<string, unknown> // Content value could be a string, or a nested object
type I18n = Record<string, I18nContent> // API always returns an object with namespace as key, and object (possibly nested) as value

const i18nContent: I18n = {
  common: {
    error: {
      missing_translation: 'Missing translation',
      missing_posts: 'Some articles are not available in this language'
    },
    languages_available: 'This article is available in other languages'
  }
}

const t = (key: string): string => {
  const kArray = key.split('.')
  
  const keyValue = kArray.reduce((o: unknown, k: string) => {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object' && Object.keys(o).length && o[k as keyof typeof o] !== 'undefined') {
      return o[k as keyof typeof o]
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }, i18nContent)

  return typeof keyValue === 'string' ? keyValue : key
}
```

I'm quite new to Typescript, so I'll be happy to get some feedbacks and maybe advices on this refacto?

Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: Type of `reduce` predicate return value  should match the type of `acc` (second argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `reduce` function return type as type of initial value so I change a bit in your code to support i18n nested multi level object.

```
interface ITranslationContent {
  [key: string]: string | ITranslationContent;
}

const i18nContent: ITranslationContent = {
  common: {
    error: {
      missing_translation: 'Missing translation',
      missing_posts: 'Some articles are not available in this language',
      http_code: {
        unauthorized: '401'
      }
    },
    languages_available: 'This article is available in other languages'
  }
}

const t = (key: string): string | ITranslationContent => {
  const kArray = key.split('.')
  let res: string | ITranslationContent = i18nContent;
  kArray.forEach((k: string) => {
    res = typeof res === 'string' ? res : res[k];
  })
  return res || key;
}
```

Comment: I thought there could be a solution based on initial reduce one, but this one using forEach seems finally cleaner, thx!
Btw, I didn't know it was possible to define an interface this way, very happy to have learn this tip!